# How to fix this error ("_OBJC_CLASS_$_AsyncSocket", referenced from:)

Tags: ios, asyncsocket

When I added `AsyncSocket.h`and `.m`to my project I got this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
" _OBJC_CLASS_$_AsyncSocket", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 steps to fix the problem :

1. Add `CFNetwork.framework` to the project
2. Select `AsyncSocket.m` from Xcode navigator (left side) and from **inspector** (right side) mark your project NAME under **Target Membership** section

or go to    Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > click (+) > add `AsyncSocket.m`

Answer (score 0):

Add Security.framework to Link Binary with Library:)